# C : Output printing a line later

Tags: c

I wrote this small program to count the number of trailing zeroes. I got my algorithm correct. But I cannot get the output right. The first line we enter is for the number of inputs (`T`). Later the user enters the number (whose number of trailing zeroes in factorial is to be calculated.) And then print the answer (`count`). But after I input the value for `N`, I get the answer on the third line (I used just one `'\n'`). I need to get my output right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int T;
    int i,j,temp,count=0;
    long int N;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        scanf("\n%ld",&N);
        for(j=5;j<=N;j+=5)
        {
            temp=j;
            while(j > 1)
            {
                if(j%5 == 0)
                    count++;

                j=j/5;
            }
            j=temp;
        }
        printf("\n%d",count);       
        count =0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first rule to getting your output right is to learn that newlines should go at the end of print statements, not at the beginning. Good output should end in a new line.

Comment: printf("%d\n",count);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
printf("\n%d",count);
```

to:

```
printf("%d\n",count);
```

and:

```
scanf("\n%ld",&N);
```

to:

```
scanf("%ld",&N);
```

Comment: The first (`printf()`) change is crucial; the second (`scanf()`) change is optional.  The newline in the format is 'white space' and means white space will be skipped, but the `%ld` will also skip white space.

Comment: Isn't it a better practice to avoid `\n` in `scanf()` though?

Comment: Yes; it is better to avoid newlines in `scanf()` (if only because it doesn't mean what it looks as if it means), but it doesn't materially affect the correct operation of the code in the question.  A trailing newline in the `scanf()` format string would be a (usability) disaster; the input would not terminate until you type something other than white space for input to whatever will be the next prompt.